# Is it possible to insert spanned columns into datagridview column?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a question, but I can't find the answer, can someone help me?
I need to create in a datagridview one column which spans multiple columns, this must look like following example:

[image]

In the grid I need to have detail about every day and every hour, what a person did in each hour. Is it possible to do this in a datagridview? Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descripted functionality is not supported by standard DataGridView control. You could solve it by choosing from following opinions:

- create your own user control
- you can modify standard DataGridView control, for example like in this link: [How can merge a particular column header in DataGridView C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366436/how-can-merge-a-particular-column-header-in-datagridview-c)
- use some extension library like DevExpress. Similar walkthrough like described here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2472

Comment: Thank you for answer, this is exacty that I need, this help me a lot

Comment: I do this and work very fine, thank you a lot, a beer from me :D