# How to group column of datagridview

Tags: .net, visual-studio, datagridview

I need to make a datagridview like this.
Qty,Unit price and Amount columns are sub column of Credit Note and Debit Note Column. Do you think it's possible in Visual Studio 2013?

[image]

Comment: I found the answer without third party.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366436/how-can-merge-a-particular-column-header-in-datagridview-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default .net DataGridview control does not allow this functionality, but yes multiple third party tools provide this kind of support. like DevExpress, Telerik etc.