# How to use a single DataGridView header for two columns with data binding?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following requirement: on a system we have a grid of customers, each customer has a boolean property `Maintenance` and an integer property `NumberOfMaintenances`, and what is required is that on a DataGridView we have just the header `Maintenance` and below it two columns: one with checkboxes for the boolean and another for the int.

The main point is that the user wants *both* information below the same header, and not two headers.

The customer data is being populated via databinding, and in that situation, I can't find a solution to do it, because I have already the columns defined to match the properties of the type being bound to the datagridview.

How can I do this? How can I have a single header for two columns below it when using data binding with a datagridview?

Comment: You can use the `.Paint()` event of your DataGridView to draw whatever you want, headers included. Use the `dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle()` of the two columns you want to _merge_ and paint the new header with those dimensions (you can use `e.Graphics.FillRectangle()` and `e.Graphics.DrawString()`.

Comment: In this SO answer, [How can merge a particular column header in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366436/how-can-merge-a-particular-column-header-in-datagridview-c) there's more or less what I described (a bit messy, but you'll get the idea).